# object not fire click event in meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have this template:

```
<template name="article">
   <input id="name_inputer" type="text" value={{title}}>
   <div id="display_panel">
     {{someData}}
   </div>
</template>
```

and have this template events (in coffeescript)

```
Template.article.events

  'blur #name_inputer': (event, template)->
    Article.save ...                          #1

  'click #display_panel': (event, template)->
    ...do something                           #2
```

When I focus in the input and type something, then click the div
only #1 is fired and #2 was not working.

Why?

Comment: Do you get any error logs? Have you tried identifying the elements by their `class` rather than the `id`?

Comment: @apendua, thanks for comment. No any logs and same for `class`. btw: what the difference between `class` or `id`?

Comment: Are you sure that `{{someData}}` isn't empty and the `#display_panel` div has a height so that its clickable?